# Meaning of constructor with multiple pairs of parentheses

Tags: c++, function, constructor, declaration

I'm not sure about this piece of code:

```cpp
someClass(std::list<std::function<void(std::vector<someType>&)>>(&)(const std::vector<someType>&)) {
    ...
}
```

The constructor for `someClass`, I believe, takes a reference to a list of functions, each of which will return `void` and take a reference to a vector of `someType`. 
What I'm not sure about is the last pair of parentheses, `(const std::vector<someType>&)`. Is `operator()` of `std::list` being overloaded here?

In addition, I'd like to name the `std::list` parameter, but my initial guess of `someClass(std::list<...>(& nameOfList)(...))` did not work, as I cannot access `nameOfList.begin()`, for example. What would I do here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a function by itself.

```
std::list<
         std::function<
            void(std::vector<someType>&)
         >
> (&)(const std::vector<someType>&)
```

This is a reference to a function that takes as an argument a reference to const `std::vector` of `someType` and returns a list of `std::function`s that take a reference to a `std::vector` of `someType` and return `void`.

Usage example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
class someType {};
void func(std::list<std::function<void(std::vector<someType>&)>> (& par)(const std::vector<someType>&)) {
    // some input
    const std::vector<someType> input;
    // the function returns the list
    std::list<std::function<void(std::vector<someType>&)>> res = par(input);
    // we can iterate over the list
    for (auto & i : res) {
        std::vector<someType> other;
        // and call the functions inside
        i(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The parameter of the constructor

```
someClass( std::list<std::function<void(std::vector<someType>&)>>(&)(const std::vector<someType>&)) {
```

is a reference to a function that has the return type `std::list<std::function<void(std::vector<someType>&)>>` and one parameter of the type `const std::vector<someType>&`

Comment: Thank you, Vlad, for the answer as well as the edit! Clear and to the point, but I'll have to accept @kamil-cuk's answer, as his example provided a clear example. Thank you.

Comment: @jmkjaer Don't bother. Be happy.:)